How much harder does your body have to work to remove CO2 after you drink a soda?
CO2 is a toxic waste byproduct of our body's metabolism. No matter how its created it's still carbon dioxide and poisonous to us. Should we really be making our drinks fizzy with it? I would really like to know how much harder our body's have to work after we drink a single soda to remove just the CO2.

Is a few burps a hard work?

and the little bit that gets absorbed into the blood stream is almost immediately exhaled.

BTW, canned whipped cream is often made using nitrous oxide, though it would be unaesthetic to use in soda/tonic/seltzer,club soda/pop. As soft drink it would be a hard drink.

@DrMoishePippik  In old days, there were sold "little bombs" of liquified CO2/N2O to make homemade soda/whipped cream in the specialized devices. My grandmother once confused them and we got for free interesting experience of carbonized whipped cream. :-)

@Poutnik, they're both still sold, e.g., on Amazon... and I remember the days of glass seltzer bottles, with glass "straw", delivered by the case -- and tried to used one to put out a fire.

Your premise is not right. $\ce{CO2}$ is essential to human body and you would be dead without it. But as with all chemicals including water, it is the dose what makes the poison. The body eliminates just excess of it.
Most of soda drink $\ce{CO2}$ is expelled by burps, if the swallowed volume of soda drink is rather big. The rest that is absorbed and finally comes to blood is easily expelled by breathing.
$\ce{CO2}$ content in soda drinks is typically $\pu{3-4 g/L}$. With typical breathing in rest $\pu{16 \times 500 mL/min}$ with $4\%\  \ce{CO2}$, a body expels about $\pu{0.6 g/min }\ce{CO2}$. So a body in rest expels during $\pu{5-7 min}$ the amount of $\ce{CO2}$ contained in the whole $\pu{1 L}$ of soda drink. Much more  by intense, fast and deep breathing.
But no reasonable person drinks $\pu{1 L}$ of soda drink in $\pu{5 min}$ and if one does, majority of $\ce{CO2}$ would not be absorbed.
Too intense breathing for too long (hyperventilation) may lead to respiratory alkalosis, caused by lack of $\ce{CO2}$. The body fluids and blood especially rely on $\ce{CO2/HCO3-}$ pH buffer.

"Death by cola" does happen, apparently.

There is the Czech proverb "Ničeho příliš!" ( "Avoid extremes!").

The effect was mechanical, not chemical. Too much in too short time. // In endurance sport activities, it is often adviced that water absoption rate is 800 mL/h, best drinking it in several 100-200 mL doses per hour. Aand not more than 400 mL at once. // What I often do, if I want to drink larger volume of carbonated drink is repeatedly squeezing PET to have minimal head space and shaking it up to pressurize it again. I do not really like drinking substantial volume at once if too carbonated.

Yes, I read the entire newspaper article and seems there is reason to doubt death was due to CO2 intoxication. There were "extenuating" circumstances, as they say.

as evidence that the body can tolerate lots of CO2 in the gut, many colon screening procedures now use CO2 to inflate the large intestine for viewing rather than air (ie mostly nitrogen) because the body absorbs the CO2 fairly quickly (reducing distension) and it is does not have to be "expelled", as the nitrogen was. That significantly reduces discomfort for patients.
